# Is "pying" a valid word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I may not be spelling or using it correctly, but I often use the word "pying" to say one is seeking out something that belongs to another. Perhaps the word is altogether nonexistent and I have completely fabricated a word which I have been using in several essays. I nearly always follow the word with "for" as the letter Q is followed by U. Maybe a word like this exists and I have substituted it for a make believe one. It carries the meaning but not the arbitrarily assigned mashup of letters attributed to it.

Example uses:

"By then, their hunger had set in and were all pying for bread and coin."

"With all these companies pying for your money, it leaves a detrimental..."

"Prying and prodding and pying for a rare peek into the secret life..."

Comment: "Perhaps the word is altogether nonexistent and I have completely fabricated a word."  Well, I guess it's time to send a letter to Merriam Webster and Oxford.

Comment: Plying, spying, prying, crying?

Comment: You seem to use it like a verb, what would be the infinitive? _To py_?

Comment: Do you have reference to it's use anywhere?

Comment: @HotLicks it's listed by [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pying)

Comment: @JJJ - Not a very credible (or even understandable) listing.  8 upvotes and 10 downvotes.

Comment: @HotLicks some others use it as a [Twitter hashtag](https://twitter.com/hashtag/pying). Some of them are used with Thai and Chinese characters (this being the only latin characters in the tweet), some seem to be misspellings of _prying_.  I can't really derive the meaning from the tweets though. Also [some listings in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pying%22).

Comment: @HotLicks that UD definition seems to be the only reference to the word that I can find.

Comment: @TommyWoldt - So what makes you think it's a "word", by any reasonable definition?  Where did you get it?

Comment: @JJJ - Did you look at those Google Books hits?  The latter half of hyphenated "occu-pying", OCR misread of "dying", and the latter half of the name of some Oriental river.

Comment: @HotLicks I did, I found, I answered. :)

Comment: Maybe you are ***Prying and prodding and spying for a rare peek into the secret life***....

Comment: '... and were all **pining** for bread and coin' and 'companies pining for your money'?

Comment: Could you mean vying? - by way of Mandela effect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may mean [***pining***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pine-for-sth-sb), which is, indeed, virtually always followed by "for" and would (more-or-less) fit into all of your examples. From Cambridge Dictionaries:

> **pine for sth/sb**
>   — phrasal verb with pine
>   to want or miss something or someone very much

It's more commonly used with the "miss someone" meaning, but it sounds like you are using it more with the "want something" part of the definition.

Answer (score 8):

I think you mean "vying"--you probably heard it some time and thought the v was a p.

"vying" is the present participle of "vie" [to vie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vie)

> to compete: Several companies are vying for the contract to build the
>   new hospital.

Answer (score 2):

**Pying** is a word. By googling, I found it's a term used in agriculture in the early 1800s.

Take this excerpt from [*A Plain and Easy Introduction to the Knowledge and Practice of Gardening*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EnM-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=pying+potatoes&source=bl&ots=kQPCqVcv6g&sig=gctwOFAbpS4qkTwhNGltKR2gwL0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieqa_c-LzaAhXCKFAKHYm_DLgQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=pying%20potatoes&f=false):

> **Pying** (as it is called in some places) is a good method of preserving potatoes in winter. They are piled on the surface of the ground, in a rigid form, of a width and length at pleasure, according to the quantity, but commonly about six feet wide. 
>   This is done by digging a spit of earth, and laying it round the edge, a foot wide (if turf the better) filling the space up with straw, and then laying on a course of potatoes, dig earth from the outside, and lay upon the first earth. 
>   Put straw a few inches along the inside edge, then put in more potatoes, and so on, keeping a good coat of straw all the way up between the potatoes and the mould, which should be about six inches thick all over; beat it close together, and the form it lies in, with the trench all round, will preserve the potatoes dry; and the sharpest frost will hardly affect them; in a severe time of which, the whole may be covered with straw. 
>   In the spring, look over the stock, and break off the shoots of those designed for the table, and repeat this business, to preserve the potatoes longer good.

Attribution: Rivington, F. and Rivington, J. (1800). A Plain and Easy Introduction to the Knowledge and Practice of Gardening. [online] Google Books. Available at: https://books.google.com/books?id=EnM-AAAAYAAJ&dq=pying+potatoes&source=gbs_navlinks_s [Accessed 15 Apr. 2018].